# I can't fully understand why the program isn't working - LCD Screen problems and more

Tags: arduino

I'm working on a project for an automatic Malteser (or similar product) dispenser and I got the code to work, but after leaving it it for a bit, the screen played up and it won't work properly. The LED also is always on and it can seem to move on from the Setup

I have tried:

- searching the code for faults
- checking the wiring
- redoing the wiring in case i missed something

Code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <DS3231.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

DS3231 Clock;
bool Century = false;
bool h12;
bool PM;
byte ADay, AHour, AMinute, ASecond, ABits;
bool ADy, A12h, Apm;
int second, minute, hour, date, month, year, temp;
int button = 8;
int maltesersEaten = 0;
int lastEatenSe = 0;
int lastEatenMi = 0;
int lastEatenHo = 0;
int lastEatenDa = 0;
int lastEatenMo = 0;
int lastEatenYe = 0;
bool eat;
int ledPin = 10;

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

Servo myServo;

byte degree[8] = {
  B00100,
  B01010,
  B00100,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
};

void setup() {
  **lcd.createChar(0, degree);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);  
  // Print a message to the LCD
  lcd.print("INITIALIZING");
  // Start the I2C interface
  Wire.begin();
  // Start the serial interface
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
  myServo.attach(9);**
  myServo.write(10);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
}

void getData() {
  second = Clock.getSecond();
  minute = Clock.getMinute();
  hour = Clock.getHour(h12, PM);
  date = Clock.getDate();
  month = Clock.getMonth(Century), DEC;
  year = Clock.getYear();
  temp = Clock.getTemperature();

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(hour);
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.print(minute);
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.print(second);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(date);
  lcd.print(",");
  lcd.print(month);
  lcd.print(",");
  lcd.print(year);
  lcd.setCursor(9, 0);
  lcd.print(temp);
  lcd.write(byte(0));
  lcd.print("C");
  lcd.setCursor(9,1);
  lcd.print("ATE:");
  lcd.print(maltesersEaten);
}

void mE() {
  maltesersEaten = (maltesersEaten + 1);
  lastEatenSe = second;
  lastEatenMi = minute;
  lastEatenHo = hour;
  lastEatenDa = date;
  lastEatenMo = month;
  lastEatenYe = year;
}



void check() {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("-Last Malteser-");
  delay(500);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(hour);
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.print(minute);
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.print(second);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Eaten: ");
  lcd.print(maltesersEaten);
  delay(5000);
  lcd.clear();
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(button) == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    myServo.write(170);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("---- Have A ----");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("    Malteser    ");
    delay(5000);
    myServo.write(10);
    lcd.clear();
    check();
    mE();
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }

  else if (digitalRead(button) == HIGH) {
    getData();
  }
}
```

The desired effect would be the screen produces a message, the LED flashes, then it shows the time, date and temperature of the room, as well as how many Maltesers have been eaten. then when the button is pressed, the servo moves, the LED turns on and the LCD changes through a few different screens, then it returns to the time, date, temp, and number of Maltesers eaten. However the actual result is that the LED turns on permanently, the LCD produces two solid blocks and nothing else, and the servo goes limp, when I press the button nothing changes. I think the problem is in the setup if that is of nay help.

Answer (score 0):

In the program you call the function: check(). In there is a five second delay and in the loop there is another 5s delay. Could it be that you always press the button when the delay is on. Then the program would not notice that the button was pressed and continues with the loop again. This would also explain why the led won't turn off because it is turned on again right away.
To test if this is the case just hold the button down for at least 10s and sea if it works.
If this is the case, to fix this problem try working with an interrupt.
See documentation here: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/